# Fourier Series of a $2\pi$-Periodic Function

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Assume that $f$ is a $2\pi$−periodic and integrable function defined on $\mathbb{R}$, and suppose that $f(\theta + \pi) = f(\theta)$ for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all odd $n$.

Using here that $$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) e^{-inx}dx$$

I tried expanding this to $$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \big(\cos(nx) + i\sin(nx)\big)dx$$ but I don't see how the expression changes for odd $n$.

Comment: Hint: If $n$ is odd, then $e^{-inx}=-e^{-in(x+\pi)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\int_{0}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}dx=\int_{-\pi}^0 f(x+\pi)e^{-in(x+\pi)}dx=-\int_{-\pi}^0f(x)e^{-inx}dx$$
since $e^{-in(x+\pi)}=e^{-inx}e^{-in\pi}=-e^{-inx}$ as $n$ is odd. Hence $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}dx=0$$

Comment: How did you change the integration limits in this line?  $$\int_{0}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}dx=\int_{-\pi}^0 f(x+\pi)e^{-in(x+\pi)}dx$$

Comment: I used the substitution $u=x-\pi$

Comment: Ok then the bounds make sense, but would you not then have to use $$f(u) = f(x-\pi)$$?

Comment: No, since $x=u+\pi$ (maybe it was confusing that I used $x$ in both integrals). We get $$\int_0^\pi f(x)e^{-inx}dx=\int_{-\pi}^0 f(u+\pi)e^{-in(u+\pi)}dx$$